# $X-\bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ dense in $X$ if $X$ compact Haussdorff and $A_{n}$ nowherdense in $X$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a compact Haussdorf topological space . Prove that if $\lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ is a sequence of nowhere dense sets of $X$. Then $X-\bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ is dense in $X$.

Since $\lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$  is a sequence of nowhere dense sets of $X$, we have that $int\overline{(A_{n})} = \emptyset$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So what I intend to prove is that $ \overline{X-\bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace}=X$. Obviously since $X-\bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace \subset X$, we have that $\overline{X-\bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace} \subset \overline{X}=X$, the last contention because $X$ is clopen. So I only need to prove the contention $X \subset \overline{X-\bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace}$. By definition of complement of a closure $\overline{X-\bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace}= X-int(\bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace)$. Here I try to proceed by contradiction, asume $x \in X$ and $x \in int(\bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace)$, this means there is an open set $U$ such that $x \in U$ and $U \subset \bigcup \lbrace A_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$. If countable union of nowhere dense sets is a nowhere dense set we are done. But this is not always true. However, I was wondering how to solve this whether with my idea or another aproach? Still dont know how I can use the hypothesis of $X$ being compact or Haussdorf.

Comment: This is, essentially, the Baire Category Theorem for compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: $X-\overline{A_n}$ is open and dense for all $n$, so their intersection is dense in $X$ by the Baire category theorem and it is a subset of $X-\bigcup_n A_n$.

Comment: @Jason Where I can use Baire Category Theorem? I mean in which part of the proof I use the fact that $X$ is a Baire Space?

Comment: @Cos: $A_n$ is **not** dense in $X$: by hypothesis it is **nowhere dense** in $X$. You stated the hypothesis correctly in the question but incorrectly in the title.

Comment: Thanks!  Already corrected. But I dont understand why $X-\bar{A_{n}}$ is dense for all n? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Cos: Because $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}A_n=\varnothing$. Thus, if $U$ is any non-empty open set in $X$, $U\cap\operatorname{cl}A_n=\varnothing$, so $U\cap(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A_n)=U\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Thanks but still Im quite lost tbh. Following Brandsma idea I understand the intersection of $X- \bar{A_{n}}$ is dense in $X$ is dense in X  by BCT theorem.  However, why this intersection is contained  in $X- \cup_{n} A_{n}$ and how we are done by proving this contention? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Cos: That’s just [De Morgan’s laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Infinite_unions_and_intersections): $$\bigcap_n(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A_n=X\setminus\bigcup_n\operatorname{cl}A_n\,,$$ and of course $$X\setminus\bigcup_n(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A_n\subseteq X\setminus\bigcup_n(X\setminus A_n)\,,$$ since $$\bigcup_n(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A_n)\subseteq\bigcup_n(X\setminus A_n)\,,$$ since $X\setminus A_n\subseteq X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A_n$. We’re done because the goal was to prove that $X\setminus\bigcup_nA_n$ is dense: contains the dense set ...

Comment: ... $\bigcap_n(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A_n)$, so it is automatically dense itself.

Comment: Thanks so much! You explained quite well Herdsman idea. Im preparing myself for a graduate admission test with mocking tests, and this are questions arising from these tests. I asked a days ago a real analysis question nobody could helped me. Wondering if you can please check it out? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144866/proving-continuity-of-the-identity-among-several-norms-for-the-space-of-bouden-v?noredirect=1#comment8578149_4144866 @BrianMScott

Comment: @Cos I did not mean to say that you should *apply* the Baire Category Theorem - the statement of this problem is so similar to that of the BCT that using the theorem would make the problem rather trivial. Instead, I would look up a proof of the BCT, and try in particular to understand how compactness and the finite intersection property are important.